# Возможно ли нагрузка в данном кодинге? PHP + MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, массивы, файлы, mysqli

```
function endb_t($bat){
    $hpt=mysql_query("SELECT `fight_users`.`battle`, `fight_users`.`side`, Sum( `fight_users`.`hp` ) AS hp, Sum( `user`.`level` ) AS `level` FROM `fight_users`,`user` WHERE `fight_users`.`id`=`user`.`id` GROUP BY `fight_users`.`side`, `fight_users`.`battle` HAVING (((`fight_users`.`battle`) = '".$bat."')) ORDER BY `fight_users`.`side` LIMIT 2");
    while ($hp = mysql_fetch_assoc($hpt)) {
        $sid[$hp['side']]=$hp['hp'];
        $win[$hp['side']]=$hp['level'];
    }
    if($sid[1]==0 and $sid[2]!=0){
        $win[0]=2;
    }else if($sid[2]==0 and $sid[1]!=0){
        $win[0]=1;
    }else if($sid[1]==0 and $sid[2]==0){
        $win[0]=3;
    }else{
        $win[0]=0;
    }
    return $win;
}
```

И помогите пожалуйста, как переписать данный код под $mysqli?

Comment: Просите уж сразу переписать на PDO.

Comment: ПДО уже лучше когда начинаешь с нуля, а чтоб переписывать всё... дело не легкое, и нет времени)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно но некретично, скорее у вас связано с ошибками (не инициализированы переменные) и тем, что вы не удаляйте выборку после запроса.

```
 function endb_t (&$db_connect, $bat) {
    if (!empty($db_connect) && isset($bat)) {
        $hpt = mysqli_query($db_connect, "SELECT f.battle, f.side, Sum(f.hp) AS hp, Sum(u.level) AS level FROM fight_users f JOIN user u USING(id) GROUP BY f.side, f.battle HAVING f.battle = '{$bat}' ORDER BY f.side LIMIT 2");
        if (!empty($hpt) && mysqli_num_rows($hpt) > 0) {
            $sid = array();
            $win = array();
            while ($hp = mysqli_fetch_assoc($hpt)) {
                $sid[$hp['side']] = $hp['hp'];
                $win[$hp['side']] = $hp['level'];
            }
            mysqli_free_result($hpt);
            if ($sid[1]==0 and $sid[2]!=0) $win[0]=2;
            else if ($sid[2]==0 and $sid[1]!=0) $win[0]=1;
            else if ($sid[1]==0 and $sid[2]==0) $win[0]=3; 
            else $win[0]=0;
            return $win;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо уважаемый, ваш пост очень полезен для меня, немного изменил под себя и гуд, робит)